# How to make an argument optional?

Tags: excel, vba, openxml, ribbon

In a  code Module (named ribbon)

```
Sub Form1Show(control As IRibbonControl)  ' this is custom ribbon
    Form1.Show  ' works
End Sub
```

In ThisWorkbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call Form1.Show  '  error: argument not optional
End Sub
```

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: Couldn't just google that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164532(v=office.10).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the parameter as optional; otherwise, it is required.

```
Sub Form1Show(Optional control As IRibbonControl)
```

Comment: Hm, I still don't understand what was causing the error and why this would make it go away.